# ClassNotFoundException: com.google.inject.Module

Tags: java, dependency-injection, build.gradle, classnotfoundexception

I've never ran into this problem, so I really don't know how to fix this...

This is my build.gradle file if needed:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.3'
    }
}

group 'my.project'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.inject:guice:4.1.0'
    compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.8'
}

if (org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.current().isJava8Compatible()) {
    tasks.withType(org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc) {
        options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
    }
}

artifacts {
    archives jar
}

task sourcesJar(type: org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar, dependsOn: classes)
{
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}

build.dependsOn(sourcesJar)


shadowJar {
    classifier 'dist'

    exclude 'GradleStart**'
    exclude '.cache'
    exclude 'LICENSE*'
}
```

Some of the things I've tried while researching this problem are:

- Using the no_aop version of Guice.
- Adding JSR 330 as a dependency.
- Adding javax.inject to the classpath.

None of these things worked...

**EDIT:** I still haven't found a way to fix this. At first I thought it was the new JRE update. It did change my environment variables, and I fixed them but that didn't work either. If someone could help me out with this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you sure Guice is being added to the classpath?

Comment: I've done many projects with that same build.gradle file and there's no problems at all. It was just this time.

Comment: Strange... Well, the error does point at guice not being included

Comment: Should I try re-downloading dependencies? -> that didn't work.....

Comment: You could try. No guarantees on anything

Comment: It didn't work. :(

Comment: Check a lower version of Guice, or see if downloading the JAR file and placing it in the libs folder does anything.

Comment: That didn't work either. o.O

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because not find the jar correct, and gradle support maven, so in the another project with maven.

So use the `pom.xml` to download the jar to the location:

```
/Users/****/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/3.0
```

and after open the gradle project, it works well.

Another solution is to use guice.3.0 and replace 4.1.0